# Usage of deep learning results as bayesian prior?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, bayesian, ensemble-learning

Lets consider the following situation. We are trying to estimate the parameters for a predictor where interpretability is of importance (linear regression, logistic regression etc.). When we build our predictor model, we also try a deep learning model where we achieve higher test accuracy, but due to the non-interpretability, we cannot use this model. However, we would still like to use the information from this deep learning model.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to incorporate the accuracy from the deep learning model into (lets say) the logistic regression model?
2. Would it be possible to use the deep learning classifier as a Bayesian prior for (lets say) the logistic regression model?
3. Is this a thing in general? That is, use "advanced" models  with low to no interpretability (such as neural networks), as prior information for data distribution while estimating parameters in a model with good interpretability but lower prediction accuracy? If yes, is there any good example of this? (preferably using a deep learning model as the prior method)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to see how this approach could be of any use, since the  prior itself would be "un-interpretable". How will that help you if you can't interpret the prior?

Comment: @J.Delaney The goal is to increase accuracy of the more interpretable model. To give some background, I'm about to finish my thesis where I have compared sequential classification methods where one of the method is "interpretable" and the other is RNN/LSTM. The RNN/LSTM classifier outperforms the interpretable one, but as further work I would like to write a short summary of how one could use the RNN/LSTM classifier as prior information and perhaps increase the accuracy of the interpretable one. It's not required to work "perfectly", I'm more interested in if and how it would be possible.

Comment: Of course this can be done, but since this relies on the output of the "complicated" model as input, it seems hard to argue that the result will be "more interpretable" than just using the output of the complicated model by itself

Comment: @J.Delaney Hmm alright... My idea was that, for instance, if we have a binary classification task where the uninterpretable model get a classification distribution of 0.75/0.25 on 0's/1's, which we believe in, then we $know$ that the interpretable classifier also should get very close to a classification distribution of 0.75/0.25 on 0's/1's. My goal was to incorporate this as prior information (or bias) into the interpretable model.